# Can I looping this code in PHP using for or while?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT bobot FROM `record_result` WHERE `participantid` = $idParticipant AND `questionid` = 1";
$query1 = "SELECT bobot FROM `record_result` WHERE `participantid` = $idParticipant AND `questionid` = 2";
$comments = mysql_query($query);
$comments1 = mysql_query($query1);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   $bobot = $row['bobot'];
   $bobot = htmlspecialchars($row['bobot'],ENT_QUOTES);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   $bobot1 = $row['bobot'];
   $bobot1 = htmlspecialchars($row['bobot'],ENT_QUOTES);
}
?>
```

I want to make this code can looping until 10. I hope that there aren't many variable, ex: $query, $query1, $query2, ..., $query10, $comments, $comments1, $comments2, ..., $comments10, $bobot, $bobot1, $bobot2, ..., $bobot10. Someone help me, please ...

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. But I have to mention that you should start using parameterized queries with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of constructing your queries manually.

```
$id = 1;
while($id <= 10) {
   // construct your query
   $query = "SELECT bobot FROM `record_result` WHERE `participantid` = $idParticipant AND `questionid` = $id";
   // execute and get results
   $comments = mysql_query($query);

   // iterate over records in result
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      $bobot = $row['bobot'];
      $bobot = htmlspecialchars($row['bobot'],ENT_QUOTES);
   }

   // increment the id for next cycle through the loop
   $id = $id + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but i still found an error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in" on script "while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC))"